# com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence (XML)

Tags: java, xml, dom, encoding, utf-8

I am getting this Exceptoin and the problem is because I input characters that are utf-8 encoded.

At the top of my XML file is say : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` 
And I have added encoding. but stil I get this exception.

```
 //Set the format
    Format format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
    format.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(format);
    // Create a new file and write XML to it
    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileOutputStream(new File(XMLEditorService
            .getXMLEditorService().getFile())));
```

The error seems to occur when I parse the file :

```
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.peekChar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Post your xml file also

Answer (score 1):

You're telling the parser that the file is encoded in UTF-8, and the parser is telling you that it isn't. I'm inclined to believe the parser.

There are two approaches to diagnosis:

(a) examine the file at the binary level to see what the actual octets are, and what the actual encoding is.

(b) study how the file came into being and how badly-encoded characters might have come to be there.

Comment: I tried to insert utf-8 data from notepad and it worked fine. But when I do it from my java application I get this bug. So the error is not with the file.

Comment: Well, all I can do to help is to say that the error doesn't seem to be in the code you have shown us. Which slightly reduces the places you have to look.

Answer (score 1):

I hat the same problem. My problem was that i created a new XML file with jdom and the *FileWriter(xmlFile)*. The FileWriter is not able to create a UTF-8 File.
Instead useing the **FileOutputStream(xmlFile)** solved it.